# How to sort between two separate nested object in spring mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Let us say I have the following JSON Object

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "fruitName":{
         "name":"Apple",
         "color":"Red"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "fruitName":{
         "name":"Mango",
         "color":"Yellow"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":"3",
      "vegetableName":{
         "name":"Cabbage",
         "color":"Green"
      }
   }
]
```

I want to sort them by name alphabetically which are located inside two different fields (fruitName and vegetableName).

Is there any way to do it in Spring Mongo without modifying the JSON Object so the output would be like this.

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "fruitName":{
         "name":"Apple",
         "color":"Red"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":"3",
      "vegetableName":{
         "name":"Cabbage",
         "color":"Green"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "fruitName":{
         "name":"Mango",
         "color":"Yellow"
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it without modifying the JSON Object by using Projection with condition.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        id: 1,
        fruitName: 1,
        vegetableName: 1,
        name: { $ifNull: ['$fruitName.name', '$vegetableName.name'] },
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        name: 1
    }
}])
```

If you are using mongodb version 3.4+, then you can use addFields also.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        name: { $ifNull: ['$fruitName.name', '$vegetableName.name'] }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        name: 1
    }
}])
```

Comment: I have an issue with this. If I skip and limit the result of sort, the data returned is no longer correct.

{
         "$skip":{
            "$numberLong":"0"
         }
      },
      {
         "$limit":{
            "$numberLong":"20"
         }
      }

Comment: Can you post example of what results you are expecting and what results you are getting along with query? It will be better if you add a separate question for this.

Comment: Sorry I had a mistake translating it to spring code. I was using .then for vegetableName.name so the value of the name is always "vegetableName.name". It should be .thenValueOf so that the value would be the actual value of the object. It has nothing to do with sorting all along.